# Can I use a US SIM card on my xiaomi Note 8?

Tags: sms, xiaomi, mobile-network, dual-sim, cellular-radio

I am trying to use my Verizon SIM card as well as a SIM card from airvoice wireless on my xiaomi Note 8. It says that it's reading the cards but I don't know how to enable them if I can..
Please help?!

Answer (score 1):

Try and see.

To control the sims

- Settings
- Connections
- Sim Manager

You can enbale / disable them here.